# C# TCP, Socket connection dropping

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Okay, so im having issues with getting data from Socket, basically whenever i try to recieve data async, with cancellation token, if there was no response from the server, my connection gets dropped. (when operation gets cancelled by the cancellation token)

```
 try
    {
     
        await Socket!.SendAsync(request, SocketFlags.None, ct);

        if (!expectResponse)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var receivedData = new List<byte>();
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[256];
            int bytesRead = await Socket.ReceiveAsync(tempBuffer, SocketFlags.None, ct);
            receivedData.AddRange(tempBuffer[..bytesRead]);

            if (ResponseEndsWithTerminationSequence(receivedData.ToArray(), terminationSequence))
            {
                return receivedData.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);
        _ = Task.Run(() => ReconnectAsync(cts.Token));
        Debug.WriteLine($"Exception occurred during data transmission!\n{ex.Message}");
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine($"Elapsed: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    }
```

I've tried all the different ways to read from socket, even pipelines, and im having simillar issues. It always drops the connection. While when i tried with python programming language this didnt happen.

Comment: If the server do not respond, is it not expected that the connection gets closed? You might want to read [Stephen Clearys TCP FAQ](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html), especially the part about half open connections. My takeaway from that article is that if you do not *have to* use raw TCP, use some higher level protocol that takes care of these issues for you.

Comment: Since you have borh working and non-working apps, it's time to break out Wireshark. Capture both apps doing the same thing and then compare.

Comment: How long before connection is closed?  Common issue is you didn't sent a return at line of data so server is waiting for the return.  If connection closes immediately it never completed.  If connection wait a long period of time and then closes there is something wrong with the data.

Comment: @JonasH I use the Serial to TCP converter device, and as for SocketType, it's Stream.

Comment: I tried wireshark on both the programs, and on C# the program sends some reset information to the TCP server to reset it. I'm not sure, cause the server always responds with all the ACKs and the same goes for the client, but the server still resets the connection. @StephenCleary

Comment: @NightCoreHC: If you mean `RST` packets, then it's likely something is calling shutdown / close / dispose.

Comment: Well, nothing in my code was calling close or dispose, so i guess it's possible that internal code in Socket is doing something with async functions, as previously we were running everything with Sync and callbacks, but it was unreadable and really hard to add new features to code. So i tried switching to Async. @StephenCleary

Comment: @NightCoreHC: Can you post a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: I posted it as an answer cause it was too long for a comment @StephenCleary

Answer (score 0):

```
﻿using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SerialTcpClient
{
    public sealed class TcpIpClient : ITcpClient
    {
        private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new(0, 1);
        private IPEndPoint? _ipEndPoint;
        private System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient? _client;
        private int _reconnecting;
        private const int _reconnectionAttempts = 3;
        public Socket? Socket { get; }
        public bool Connected => _client?.Connected ?? false;
        public async Task<bool> OpenConnectionAsync(IPAddress ipAddress, int port, CancellationToken ct = default)
        {
            _ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
            _client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
            await _client.ConnectAsync(_ipEndPoint, ct);
            return _client.Connected;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _client?.Dispose();
        }


        public Task<byte[]?> SendRequestAsync(byte[] request, CancellationToken ct = default) => SendRequestAsync(request, Array.Empty<byte>(), true, ct);

        public Task<byte[]?> SendRequestAsync(byte[] request, byte[] terminationSequence, CancellationToken ct = default) => SendRequestAsync(request, Array.Empty<byte>(), true, ct);

        public Task<byte[]?> SendRequestAsync(byte[] request, bool expectResponse = true, CancellationToken ct = default) => SendRequestAsync(request, Array.Empty<byte>(), expectResponse, ct);

        private async Task<byte[]?> SendRequestAsync(byte[] request, byte[] terminationSequence, bool expectResponse = true, CancellationToken ct = default)
        {
            if (_client == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            try
            {
                await _semaphore.WaitAsync(ct);
                await using NetworkStream stream = _client.GetStream();
                await stream.WriteAsync(request, ct);
                if (expectResponse == false)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                var buffer = new byte[256];
                var receivedData = new List<byte>();
                while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    var receivedBytes = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, ct);
                    receivedData.AddRange(buffer[..receivedBytes]);
                    if (ResponseEndsWithTerminationSequence(receivedData.ToArray(), terminationSequence))
                    {
                        return receivedData.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);
                _ = Task.Run(() => ReconnectAsync(cts.Token));
                Debug.WriteLine($"Exception occurred during data transmission!\n{ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Debug.WriteLine($"Elapsed: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
        }

        private async Task ReconnectAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
        {
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _reconnecting, 1, 0) == 0)
            {
                var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                try
                {
                    var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

                    _client?.Dispose();
                    _client = new();
                    for (int i = 0; i < _reconnectionAttempts; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine($"Reconnecting at {_ipEndPoint!.Address}:{_ipEndPoint.Port}...");
                            await _client.ConnectAsync(_ipEndPoint, ct);
                            return;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to reconnect! An exception occured.\n{ex.Message}");
                            await Task.Delay(delay, ct);
                            delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delay.TotalSeconds * 2);
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Ellapsed: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
                    _reconnecting = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        private static bool ResponseEndsWithTerminationSequence(byte[] buffer, byte[] terminationSequence, int previous = 0)
        {
            if (terminationSequence.Length == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (buffer.Length < terminationSequence.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = previous; i <= buffer.Length - terminationSequence.Length; i++)
            {
                var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, i, terminationSequence.Length);
                if (segment.SequenceEqual(terminationSequence))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

thats the full code for TCPClient,
just send a request that doesnt respond with any response, and cancellation token of something short like 3 seconds, then try sending 1 more request after that and connection will be dropped. I tried everyway to bypass this thats why there's so much code in there with some weird reconnecting methods.

Comment: You were asked to provide minimal reproducible example, it means not only client code, but also server side code is required. It is hard to say how server works without its source code.

Comment: I don't have access to server-side code, it's a module I bought from a company (WIZnet) that makes those, so I cannot provide that. @Ryan

Comment: A minimal reproducible example should be 1) reproducible (i.e., complete enough for someone else to copy/paste into their editor and actually run) and 2) minimal (i.e., remove as much code as you can). Also, it should be part of your question, not a comment or answer.

Comment: Well, I can only provide client-sided code, as I didn't make the server-sided one at all and I don't have access to it. Also yeah I clicked the wrong button when I wanted to add that to the question. But thanks for the help anyway, I figured it was something with server-sided device, as now that I changed it I don't have the problem anymore.